# Registering a Session Scope Bean

Tags: spring

How do I register the `Session` Scope in a bundle where I am using `ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext` for the application context? 
`ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext` is not configurable, so I am having trouble finding where to do it.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>

    <param-value>
                org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm.ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```